# Should I use viewport meta in an electron app?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, electron

**I'm using This bootstrap example in my electron app:**

(https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_default&stacked=h)
Should I use viewport meta in an electron app or no?

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Is it causing a problem?

Comment: I haven't any error, But my question is, Should I use or no,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be unnecessary if you target desktop, but you should include it I believe. It won't hurt to include it since the purpose of Electron is to make your app work on every device.

Comment: Yes, Because that is for Responsive Web Design